# How to check if the checkboxlist, radiobuttonlist,dropdownlist is checked else dispaly a warning message

Tags: javascript, validation, drop-down-menu, checkboxlist, radiobuttonlist

I have multiple checkboxlists,radiobuttonlists,dropdownlists in my asp.net page. 
all the fields are required cannot be left blank. 
the number of items are too big total 73.
I was looking for an option to check the validation through java-script so if the controls are empty then i will display a warning message below each control int he current section. 
i have next buttons at the end of each section which will validate the current elements in the current section. 
any idea with the implementation of a good java-script code that can be reused for each of the list. 
A jquery will work perfectly as well

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through your checkbox/radiobutton elements and check for the .checked property. If any show up true, then display a warning.

As for the dropdown list, just check the .selectedIndex property on the 'select' element. If it's 0, then the user didn't select anything. This requires that the first item in the list not be an acceptable value (e.g., most websites make the first option something like 'Choose An Option').

Comment: I was looking for a code sample. I know this is to do but i don't know how to do that in javascript or jquery....